# Mediarecorder and javascript on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, mediarecorder

I need to save a js animation rendered on canvas, with libraries like d3.js or the such. I have made a first attempt, and the biggest problem is that the colors showing up in the video are wrong: the background is black (while it's white in the render), and the histograms colors are different, too. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Maybe this bg is empty to default (0,0,0,0). Try print  your bg w/ white color before print imagens of your animation.

Comment: I have have tried to add white background colour style to either the div containing the canvas and to the canvas itself, but I have always a back background in the video. I am using ChartJS in this test.

Comment: Color style don't print coloor in canvas. Try print a white  rect with canvas' width and height in canvas, as a animation element.

Answer (score 2):

When the `MediaRecorder` is recording the canvas, only elements inside the canvas are rendered to the video stream.

For example, if you have CSS `background-color` set on the canvas or it's container(s), media recorder won't see that.

When you do draw/update on the canvas you must first draw a background rectangle, e.g.

```js
//... during frame update, first do:

ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000"; // with your desired background color
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
```

That should fix you up.